# Uncaught TypeError: sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm is not a constructor

Tags: sapui5

I am sorry to ask this silly question but when I am initializing the simple form layout , I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm is not a constructor" . I am using below mentioned code :

```
// Add a Pagebar
    var oBar = new sap.m.Bar("idFOBar", {
        contentLeft: new sap.m.Button("idFOBackButton", {
            icon: "sap-icon://nav-back",
            press: function(){
                app.back();
            }
        })
    });

    // Simple form 


    var oButton = new sap.m.Button({text: "Press"});

    var oSimpleform = new sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm({
    title:"Elements with Simple Form Layout",
    content:[oButton]
     });    



    var oPage = new sap.m.Page({
        title: "Find Order",
        content: [oBar,oSimpleform]
    });


    return oPage;
```

I remember I implemented forms before with the same code. I am not able to understand what is wrong here ?

Regards,
MS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be, that the class sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm cannot be found, so you cannot use it as a constructor.

It seems to work when you add `sap.ui.layout` to your sap-ui-core.js-bootstrap ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jecosejoyo/1/edit?html,output)).

Another option is to call `$.sap.require("sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm");` to specifically load the SimpleForm-class.